# Como fazer um algoritimo que receba o nome de um dia da semana e mostre a materia que o estudante tem no dia

Tags: c

a parte da logica eu sei que e simples porem creio que estou errando na sintaxe, ao meu ver seria se dia == segunda printf("aula da segunda") mas asim nao da certo, alguem poderia me ajudar, estou tentando fazer em C.

"Desenvolva um programa em C que receba um dia da semana e mostre qual(is) a(s) disciplina(s) você tem naquele dia da semana"

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Lucas, edite sua pergunta e inclua o código com o que já tentou para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Tente fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){ 
    char dia[50];
    printf("Digite o dia da semana: \n");
    scanf("%s",dia);

    if(strcmp(dia,"segunda") == 0){
        printf("\nEh segunda!");
    }else{
        printf("\nNao eh segunda!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: minha dificuldade e conesguir repetir a ação entende, pois o usuario tem liberdade para digitar outros dias da semana tambem como quarta, quinta.. e pra cada dia mostra uma frase diferente isso que nao estou conseguindo fazer